# Replicate a Crunchy operator OCP cluster to VMs

Tags: postgresql, replication, operator

I am trying to implement a scenario in which there is a PostgreSQL cluster on OCP using the Crunchy operator and for *reasons* it should be replicated to a VM running a full PostgreSQL installation.

I set up a basic replication scenario, meaning I used

`pg_basebackup -h <host> -p <port> -D <directory> -U <replication-user> -Xs -R -P`

and started the database and JOY.

The problem is when I delete the pod containing the primary database, Crunchy operator handles the failover and promotion of a secondary database. As soon as it does, my VM stops replicating. If I restart the VM database cluster, it continues replicating if and only if it has the same data as the primary. If there has been some change, replication will fail and I will have to start over (pg_basebackup).

Keep in mind that I am using the NodePort service that the operator provides, so I have a host and port that always points to the primary database. That means that, for example, I don't have to change the `primary_conninfo` since that will always be correct.

Do you have any idea how I can configure that avoiding the recreation of the database using `pg_basebackup`? Ideally I would prefer something that only uses the database port, since setting up SSH from a VM to a container on OCP would not be pretty.

Database Logs:

```
2023-07-20 13:42:25.194 EEST [4102] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read-only connections
2023-07-20 13:42:25.655 EEST [4107] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/5D000000 on timeline 17
2023-07-20 13:43:29.597 EEST [4107] LOG:  replication terminated by primary server
2023-07-20 13:43:29.597 EEST [4107] DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 17 at 0/5E0000A0.
2023-07-20 13:43:29.597 EEST [4107] FATAL:  could not send end-of-streaming message to primary: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
        no COPY in progress
2023-07-20 13:43:29.597 EEST [4103] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/5E0000A0: wanted 24, got 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the error messages you get when replication fails.

Comment: Edited the post with the logs.

Comment: Based on that information, the log from the primary would be interesting as well.